# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

Tags: aem, apache-felix

I am trying to implement the following article 
 http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-cq/using/creating-cq-bundles-consume-web.html
 But stuck with the below error while rendering the component in the page.
 I have added the below jars bundles in Felix:

```
jaxws-api-2.1-1-osgi.jar  
jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar  
javax.jws-1.0.jar
```

Is there any bundle still needs to be added for resolving the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
at org.apache.sling.commons.classloader.impl.ClassLoaderFacade.loadClass(ClassLoaderFacade.java:127)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.safeLoadClass
```

Comment: Did you follow the **note** under `Article summary` of the article?

Comment: Thanks Tuan Dang..It works after the adding the "sling.bootdelegation.com.sun=com.sun.*" property

Comment: Can you explain? I have a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a classloading issue with your application, or the application server.

The ClassNotFoundException will occur the first time the class is referenced and the classloader tries to load it. The next time the class is referenced, the classloader has cached that is is not found and will throw a NoClassDefFoundError.

- Confirm that the ClassNotFoundException is not being caused by the class not being packaged correctly or other classloader settings. Also, ensure the ClassNotFoundException is not occurring the first time the class is referenced.
- Check to see if there are any symlinks in the JBoss path.
- That will tell us the classes you have deployed to your application, and allow us check if com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl or a related class is deployed to it. That class is shipped with the application server in this directory, and I think this should be the only location it is loaded from.

  src/jboss-as/thirdparty/sun-jaxws/lib/jaxws-rt.jar
- The only reference I can find to the message "classLoader is not connected to a domain (probably undeployed?) for class "